# TestContainers, Spring Webflux, JUnit 5, MySQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer using @DynamicPropertySource

Tags: java, mysql, testcontainers, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I'm trying to do the following; 
but using **org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer** 
can anyone show me how this can be achieved, as MySQLR2DBCDatabaseContainer doesn't seem to have the following methods:

- ::getJdbcUrl
- ::getPassword
- ::getUsername

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationIT {
  @Container
  public static PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer()
    .withPassword("inmemory")
    .withUsername("inmemory");
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void postgresqlProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
  }
  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Would "Database containers launched via R2DBC URL scheme" work for you?
https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/r2dbc/

Answer (score 7):

For your case, you should create properties to a R2dbc connection instead of the Jdbc connection.

**You have to compute the R2dbc URL manually instead of the Jdbc URL.**

```java
registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url", () -> "r2dbc:postgresql://"
                + postgreSQLContainer.getHost() + ":" + postgreSQLContainer.getFirstMappedPort()
                + "/" + postgreSQLContainer.getDatabaseName());
registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username", () -> postgreSQLContainer.getUsername());
registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password", () -> postgreSQLContainer.getPassword());
```

More simply you can create a `tc` profile based application config for testcontainers.

```
# src/test/resources/application-tc.properties
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:tc:mysql:///databasename?TC_IMAGE_TAG=8
```

The `tc` in the url will start a testcontaienrs docker automatically. See the [TestContainers R2dbc support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/r2dbc/).

Then you can also apply some some initial work(eg. create schemas and insert sample data) via a `@TestConfiguration`.

```java
@DataR2dbcTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("tc")// activate the `tc` profile.
public class TestcontainersPostRepositoryTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

            ConnectionFactoryInitializer initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
            initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

            CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
            populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql")));
            populator.addPopulators(new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("data.sql")));
            initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);

            return initializer;
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    DatabaseClient client;

    @Autowired
    PostRepository posts;

//your tests...
```

I have some testcontainers examples.

1. Launch Contrainer via R2dbc url, see [this R2dbc MySQL example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/legacy/boot-data-r2dbc-mysql/src/test/java/com/example/demo/TestcontainersPostRepositoryTest.java).
2. Manual setup with Junit, see [this R2dbc PostgresSQL example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/legacy/boot-data-r2dbc-postgresql/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java).
3. Use spring initializer classes to initialize a Container, see [this Neo4j Rx example](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/legacy/boot-data-neo4j-rx/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryTest.java).

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a little bit tricky. If you're using reactive repositories you should continue using `MySQLContainer`, but you have to change the way you set the datasource (my code is slightly different but I hope is close enough to give you an idea of how to solve your problem). Please note the use of `UserRepositoryIntegrationTest::r2dbcUrl`.

```
@Testcontainers
@DataR2dbcTest
class UserRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Container
    private static MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0.28");

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerDynamicProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.url", UserRepositoryIntegrationTest::r2dbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.username", database::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.r2dbc.password", database::getPassword);

        registry.add("spring.flyway.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.flyway.user", database::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.flyway.password", database::getPassword);
    }

    private static String r2dbcUrl() {
        return String.format("r2dbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s",
                database.getContainerIpAddress(),
                database.getMappedPort(MySQLContainer.MYSQL_PORT),
                database.getDatabaseName());
    }
}
```

You can have a look at my repo; I got stuck in the same problem for days: **[UserRepositoryIntegrationTest.java](https://github.com/kumo829/StudentsProfileManager/blob/master/microservices/account-service/src/test/java/com/javatutoriales/profiles/account/integration/UserRepositoryIntegrationTest.java)**